# Where can I download processed data of the Kepler telescope?

Tags: kepler, light-curve

I search for lightcurve Kepler data: time $t_i$, flux $F_i$ and measurement uncertainties $\sigma_i$ I need processed data (after removing trends, normalized, etc.).  Where can I find it?

Comment: Why couldn't you find https://keplerscience.arc.nasa.gov/data-products.html

Comment: Actually I did but I don't know where to go to find a txt with these 3 columns between all the hyperlinks...

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is here. http://archive.stsci.edu/kepler/search_retrieve.html
This one is good for exoplanet light-curves https://exo.mast.stsci.edu/